# Server not running in node/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, mean-stack

**My code of server.js is:**

```
var express = require('express');

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){

    app.set('views', ___dirname + '/server/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
});

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});
var port = 3030;
app.listen(port);
console.log('listening on Port' + port + '....');
```

And the problem is:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (F:\MeanSite\server.js:7:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3
```

10 Jul 14:21:07 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes bef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have copied that code from an obsolete documentation or blog, the `configure` method has been removed in Express 4.

See [Migrating to Express 4](http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html) and specifically

> app.configure() has been removed. Use process.env.NODE_ENV or
>   app.get('env') to detect the environment and configure the app
>   accordingly.

**Fast fix:** change

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', ___dirname + '/server/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
});
```

to

```
app.set('views', ___dirname + '/server/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```